# TypeError using timedelta, cannot sum times

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I have data that looks like this:

```
    user                in               out location  flag     Time
0    ron  12/21/2021 10:11  12/21/2016 17:50     home     0  4:19:03
1    ron  12/21/2016 13:26  12/21/2016 13:52   office     2  0:25:28
2  april   12/21/2016 8:12  12/21/2016 17:27   office     0  8:15:03
3  april  12/21/2016 18:54  12/21/2016 22:56   office     0  4:02:36
4   andy   12/21/2016 8:57  12/21/2016 12:15     home     0  2:59:40
```

I want to sum or take the max value of time per user based on the flag. So I converted the column to timedelta.

```
sample.loc[:,'Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(sample['Time'])
```

However, when I try to test this by summing the entire column

```
sum(sample['Time'])
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Timedelta'
```

What am I missing here? I thought you could sum with Timedelta.

Comment: you can sum it, but your structure is not clear, is this in one column ?

Comment: yes, 'Time' is a single column in the dataframe. I was summing the column as a test to see if it would work @Datanovice

Comment: can you `print(sample.head(5))`  and paste it here ?

Comment: Sure, I've edited my post to show the data better @Datanovice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's `sum`, by default, assumes you are summing integers. Hence it tries to start summing from `0`, which is where this error comes from. It's impossible to add `0` to a timedelta.

This can be fixed in 2 ways:

- Provide a different starting value to `sum`, perhaps an "empty" `timedelta`, as the second argument for [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

  ```
  from datetime import timedelta
  ...
  sum(sample['Time'], timedelta())
  ```
- Use [`Series.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sum.html) (which will probably have better performance anyway):

  ```
  sample['Time'].sum()
  ```

Answer (score -1):

In order to take the sum of the number of days that you received using pd.to_timedelta(), you need to do the following:

```
sum(sample.Time.astype('int'))/8.64e+13
```

That is, you need to convert the 'Time' column integer to perform the sum() operation. *8.64e+13 is to convert the ns to days.*