# Trouble summing timedelta objects; previously recommended solutions don't work in python 3.7

Tags: python, python-datetime, timedelta

I have a followup on this question about summing time delta objects: [TypeError using timedelta, cannot sum times](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60804162/1086346)

Answers to that question explain that sum() expects to add integers, and you need to make sure it knows you are adding time delta objects.  Solution is to insert a list item "datetime.timedelta(0)" to give sum the hint.

I do not understand this error I'm getting in python 3.7. As in other question, I need a sum of time delta objects.  Was trying code that used a list comprehension to extract timedelta values, got same error as other question:

```
sum([i.time_idle for i in qalt])
*** TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Timedelta'
```

The puzzle for me is that the second object in my list is actually the one that is recommended as the solution in the previous question. Inspect

```
[i.time_idle for i in qalt]
[Timedelta('0 days 00:18:40.649903'), datetime.timedelta(0)]
```

I can add the time delta objects manually:

```
 tlist = [i.time_idle for i in qalt]
 tlist[0] + tlist[1]
 Timedelta('0 days 00:18:40.649903')
```

However, the sum function still does not work

```
 sum(tlist)
*** TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Timedelta'
```

In case you want to play with this, I believe following provides an MRE test case:

```
 klist = [datetime.timedelta(days=0, hours=0, minutes=18, seconds=40), datetime.timedelta(0)]
```

You'll see that `sum(klist)` fails, but can run `klist[0] + klist[1]`

I'm using a workaround that harkens back to my C roots:

```
time_idle_total = datetime.timedelta(seconds=0)
for i in qalt:
    time_idle_total += i.time_idle
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of it in terms of your workaround loop:

```py
time_idle_total = datetime.timedelta(seconds=0)
for i in qalt:
    time_idle_total += i.time_idle
```

What `sum` does is effectively this:

```py
time_idle_total = 0
for i in qalt:
    time_idle_total += i.time_idle
```

The second argument of `sum` gives the initial value to begin the sum, but you only pass one argument to `sum` (a list which happens to have a timedelta zero as its second element). So you still need to use
`sum([i.time_idle for i in qalt], datetime.timedelta(0))`

Note that
`sum((i.time_idle for i in qalt), datetime.timedelta(0))`
should be slightly faster (generator comprehension instead of list).

Comment: Thanks. I understand now.  sum() sees my list as one list argument, not as several timedelta objects.